# It is possible to stream voice from phone mic to Bluetooth speaker using HFP or HSP (api level 19-22)?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have some apps to play music, or audio file to bluetooth speaker or headset successfully, all the proccess made with AudioTrack loading media, but now it is necessary to me, to capture the input from the phone mic and stream it to a bluetooth speaker or headset.

```
AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                    RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNEL,
                    RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, minsize);
```

Now, my question is, it is possible to achieve this with android sdk level from 19 and above using hsp, hfp or a2dp?

Answer (score 0):

On Android you might use A2DP source to playback the audio out to remote, however for HF I don't think you can transfer the audio to remote since the HF/HS audio was configured directly from PCM->chip->air->chip->pcm out.

Comment: I prefer a2dp too, but android documentation is a little poor about this profile, i want to know if there are already an implementation i can use, whitout taking the hard way.

Comment: can your apps simulate a media player to do that?